# cannot input more than 1025 characters using raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to input a really huge string as input to my python script but raw_input() function is accepting only max of 1025 characters. I am on python 2.7. Is there any internal variable to be updated?

Comment: Add code as well, it will help us to understand as it shouldn't be like that (i.e. input length is not limited as @KauziJoshi has already suggested)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to what `raw_input` can read. Make sure that your data doesn't contain any newlines, as raw_input stops reading when it sees one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as the maximum amount of characters that raw_input can take, I think you have a problem with your implementation!

```
>>> val = raw_input() 

qtqqdssnankvytyodjtfuaonivepnpmnqwqhmlckvzeoewcvlycoirxvyqabmgbyoidaasdoegtwgrqpuatbcxzvrzmhuoxgsubwmwgrardwlkdnurqkwuqjgvvwhmbuodhhtlkjsnfrdfjbwgdlokidtjvxxnamxxqmafouuoijuacjzbvjaaqzjoxwzahxncenhflgrcvfhvqiowjrtzkwwbhuxbdqsmneyaiedvjmokqmgpjukhwktvfbcgojyabrnxojlfameyzewcnjaiuljnwkhqycwhihsjeehvdpjzlyejjsfwjivwmbwlzvkqkbigicuyhnuiwuxhzccbajplzqlzsqzmfrjacjtqiqfqwjatlosohhcuxutnacmtyrujivjwetkcqjlgdohdkmczdubevahvlyebxoaylqmkleeehjyhfwryjhqeyssngtqkwyhbybxbinmnzdodapzfmbwazaipcxjiphopftfbxhwdqxgzuvnzcraukugzejtzgtfgoukkblugkgafuvrkuqelcytvatldattufcmbzmjphqsdrpqevyscngbsdvczzsumfphqvnvexuiawgpdkmxflbzodyebwwupyokwfgtzisrwcojbwpdsjpqtqsercbwfqbnqzvyyqtdjzmrbtprajczvmpgibjbuzsqhdavwfrymdnembdwlujdacmfnocszkxghqpoyxmjsaejfxwjvvwccrqntqpukovlkwovpgcmzaguqwfxmviufnlcjyrapgbnvgdjszncjypeeicdmtanicqytffwjcekgeopwecquegkwmvfufqzwasfoxpdwhdzlvvqxoiuuqiwjvemnvfcizbehxpocbiexfjjzcjvjsniolhmphtpgasqwrixlotcamjyxxewknjlyzzxujrtpxxxrommeyiuxsvzbkkffcuavokuuhgpvnzxzihbtfniniiiwaflgllwvoyrurufbgmjqumotnpicctfdrxqzduyzsahbgdamasdasd
>>> len(val)

1032
```

Check the above example for 1032 characters input.